# Can not open new full screen when push from tabview flutter

Tags: flutter, fullscreen, navigator

I met a problem with push method in FLutter. Firstly, I have a main screen included AppBar and body to control many screens. In child screen, I tried to push to another new screen, but it didn't open full-screen and it's attached with AppBar from mainscreen. How can I fix it or any recommend keywords?
Many thanks
[image]

Comment: Please show how and where you have added appbar code

Comment: I add AppBar into Scaffold of root. Just only in root screen

Answer (score -1):

The problem is from package https://pub.dev/packages/persistent_bottom_nav_bar. When I used Flutter default bottom navigation, the problem is solved.